# Empty model when passing JSON data from View

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, .net-core

I am currently trying to pass data from AJAX to Controller, however, the model always shows up empty/count = 0.

AJAX call:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    var url = _this.closest("form").attr("action");

    var rows = [];
    var items = $(".itemRow");

    $.each(items, function(i, item) {
      var tbOne = $(item).find("input[name='tbOne']").val();
      var tbTwo = $(item).find("input[name='tbTwo']").val();

      var row = {
        Test1: tbOne,
        Test2: tbTwo
      };
      rows.push(row);
    });

    //Let's post to server
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: rows,
        contentType: "application/json"
      })
      .done(function(result) {
        //do something with the result
      })

  });
});
```

Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Test1 {get; set;}
    public string Test2 {get; set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Insert(<SomeOtherModel> otherModel, IEnumerable<Test> model)
{
    foreach (var item in model)
    {
        // to do here
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing... I tried to search on other posts and they did relatively the same thing as I did. But I just can't get the data to my controller..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,you passed one model to controller,so the Action should have only one parameter.Furthermore,your contentType is`"application/json"`,and you data is not json data.Besides,if you want to pass json data to controller,you need to use [FromBody].

Here is a demo worked:

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Insert()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Insert([FromBody]IEnumerable<Test> model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View：

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Insert";
}

<h1>Insert</h1>
<button id="btnSubmit">submit</button>
@section scripts{ 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

        var rows = new Array();
        var row = {};
        row.Test1 = "test1";
        row.Test2 = "test2";
        rows.push(row);
        var row1 = {};
        row1.Test1 = "test11";
        row1.Test2 = "test21";
        rows.push(row1);
        var model = JSON.stringify(rows);

        //Let's post to server
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Insert",
        data: model,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    });

});
</script>
}
```

Result：
[image]

Comment: Oh my god, thank you! The `[FromBody]` was what I have been missing!

Comment: May I ask how can I pass multiple objects to controller? If my controller contains two models like the example in the question..

Comment: You can create a new model include the two models.And use the new model to pass the data.